# Resource id #10 when I want to echo a variable with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

In my database I have user: 1234 with highscore: 222

So I was thinking of getting his data like this (I only have to check for 1 user and I need just the highscore as result it exists):

```
$highscore =
    mysql_query("SELECT highscore FROM mydatabase WHERE userID = 1234");
```

Now it can happen that this user is deleted, so I want to do a check using num_rows. If the user doesn't exists anymore, set `$highscore = 1;` (cause we need this variable somewhere else):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($highscore) == 0) {
    $highscore = 1;
}
```

And now echo the result like:

```
echo '<div id="uhs">'. $highscore .'</div>';
```

The result is however: `Resource id #10`

Did some research of course and I think the problem lies in my first query, but I can't seem to fix it...

How to get the 222 echoed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to print out the resource ID of the query you just ran. To get to the actual results you have to specifically request it:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT highscore FROM mydatabase WHERE userID = 1234");
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    $score = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $score['highscore'];
}
else {
    echo 1;
}
```