# How to get the name of the table with the biggest number of rows in database

Tags: mysql, max, rows, tablename

I need to get the name of the table with the biggest number of rows, I can find the biggest number of rows with function count and than function max, but I don't know how to see from which table is that maximum, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT table_name, table_rows
FROM   information_schema.TABLES
ORDER  table_rows;
```

for all informations, and this for the biggest one:

```
SELECT table_name, table_rows
FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_rows = 
(SELECT MAX(table_rows) FROM information_schema.TABLES);
```

php:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT table_name, table_rows
    FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_rows = 
    (SELECT MAX(table_rows) FROM information_schema.TABLES)");

if (!$result) {
    echo "error"
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['table_name'];
    echo $row['table_rows'];
}
```

Comment: Like with a Ahmad code, I am getting the same error Resource id #10? Help? tnx

Comment: it could by an error on your php code, not on the select-query

Comment: when I use your php I am getting output: time_zone_transition117210

Answer (score 0):

```
show table status
```

Will give you the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $count =  "select count(*) as cnt from : {$row[0]}\n";
    $result = $mysqli->query($count);
    $row_array=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $print[$row[0]] = $row_array['cnt']; 
}
asort($print);
```

$print will hold the value of all rows count with key as table name.
With asort() you can sort it in assending order.

Comment: I wrote your code in mysql, because my script is in mysql, no in mysqli, but it's not working, I am getting error: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in. I think this row is a problem: $row_array=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);

Answer (score 0):

To get it from any database directly, run this query

```
select TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.TABLES
where TABLE_ROWS = (SELECT max(TABLE_ROWS) from information_schema.TABLES);
```

if you want to run it in php, you cannot just echo the query you have just ran 
that is why you get the Resource#10 error. check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767843/resource-id-10-when-i-want-to-echo-a-variable-with-php-and-mysql)

the solution to this is to use "mysql_fetch_assoc" as in Mikhail answer, which actually gives you the correct result:  "time_zone_transition117210"

- time_zone_transition is the table name
- 117210 is the number of rows

Since you did not understand that this was your answer, It seems you wanted to limit the query to a certain schema. 
So your complete answer in php would be as follows

```
$result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT table_name, table_rows
    FROM information_schema.TABLES 
    WHERE table_rows = (
        SELECT MAX(table_rows) FROM information_schema.TABLES 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME'
    )
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME'"
);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo 'table name is: '. $row['table_name'] .' \n ';
    echo 'number of rows is: '. $row['table_rows'] .' \n ';
}
```

Do not forget to replace YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME with the actual name in both inner and outer queries.

Comment: Your answer looks good but it might be of more benefit to the OP and any other reader, if you could explain your statement a little bit.

Comment: @Ahmad-It's not working, I put your code into mysql_query and echo it, but I am getting error Resource id #10?

Comment: @AhmadAbdelghany I use this query at the end: SELECT TABLE_ROWS, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_baza' ORDER BY TABLE_ROWS DESC LIMIT 1 , and it's working